# putting dictionary values inside a table in Django template

Tags: python, html, django, django-templates

Its my first time using Django template. I'm trying to make a table inside my page with values from a dictionary that I built consuming an API.

Here is how I'm sending the data inside my views.py:

```
    data = {
    "year_most_launches": result_launches,
    "launch_sites":response_sites,
    "launches_2019_2021":response_2019_2021
    }
return render(request,"main/launches.html", {"data":data})
```

Here is how it is my html page:

```
            <table class="table">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Year with most launches</th>
                    <th>Launch site with most launches</th>
                    <th>Number of launches between 2019 and 2021</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>{{ data["year_most_launches"] }}</td>
                    <td>{{ data["launch_sites"] }}</td>
                    <td>{{ data["launches_2019_2021"] }}</td>
                </tr>  
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

But I'm getting the following error `django.template.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: Could not parse the remainder: '["year_most_launches"]' from 'data["year_most_launches"]'`

How can I solve this? Can someone help?

Edit1: tried to use just {{ key }} instead data["key"] but now its not appearing when I render the html

[image: my html page]

Comment: Objects pass from `views.py` must be rendered with loop with and access it's properties using `result_launches.property`, etc. same for all objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
            <table class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Year with most launches</th>
                <th>Launch site with most launches</th>
                <th>Number of launches between 2019 and 2021</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>{{ year_most_launches }}</td>
                <td>{{ launch_sites }}</td>
                <td>{{ launches_2019_2021 }}</td>
            </tr>  
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

[also you can use for loop in template](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/for-loop-django-template-tags/)

Comment: I tried this and now Its rendering the page, but just the headers appear.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: sorry Im not good in English ill try my best