# for loop to populate a django template table

Tags: python, html, django, django-templates

I'm trying to make a table in Django template. I'm sending a dict as my data inside my `views.py` like this:

```
from posixpath import split
from unittest import result
from django.shortcuts import render
import requests

from .utils import most_frequent, get_json_values, get_max_dict

def launches(request):
"""main request. Retrieve the year that had most launches"""
response_launches = 
requests.get('https://api.spacexdata.com/v3/launches? 
filter=launch_year')
launches = response_launches.json()
launch_years = get_json_values('launch_year',launches)
result_launches = most_frequent(launch_years)

"""retrieve the launch site most used for launches """
response_sites = 
requests.get('https://api.spacexdata.com/v3/launches? 
filter=launch_site')
sites = response_sites.json()
launch_sites = get_json_values("launch_site", sites)
result_sites = get_max_dict(launch_sites,'site_id')

"""retrieve the number of launches between 2019 and 2021"""
response_2019_2021 = 
requests.get('https://api.spacexdata.com/v3/launches? 
start=2019&end=2021')
launches_2019_2021 = response_2019_2021.json()
result_2019_2021 = len(launches_2019_2021)

data = {
    "year_most_launches": result_launches,
    "launch_sites":result_sites,
    "launches_2019_2021":result_2019_2021
    }
print(result_launches,result_sites,result_2019_2021)
return render(request,"main/launches.html", {"data":data})
```

My `utils.py`:

```
from collections import Counter
from typing import Dict, List

def most_frequent(List) -> int:
"""return the most frequent element inside a list."""
occurence_count = Counter(List)
return occurence_count.most_common(1)[0][0]

def get_json_values(key,input_data) -> List:
"""return the values of dicts inside a list."""
return [sub_val[key] for sub_val in input_data if key in sub_val]

def max_dict_value(List,key) -> List:
"""return the key that is linked to the most frequent value."""
counts = dict()
for dictionary in List:
    counts[dictionary[key]] = counts.get(dictionary[key],0) + 1
max_keys = [key for key, value in counts.items() if value == 
max(counts.values())]
return max_keys

def get_max_dict(List,key) -> List:
"""return the dictionary that maps to the max_dict_value."""
for dictionary in List:
    if dictionary[key] == max_dict_value(List,key)[0]:
        return dictionary
```

My table in HTML code:

```
            <table class="table">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Year with most launches</th>
                    <th>Launch site with most launches</th>
                    <th>Number of launches between 2019 and 2021</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                {% for element in data.values %}
                <tr>
                    <td>{{ element }}</td>
                </tr> 
                {% endfor %} 
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

My problem is that the values of data just appears in the first column, creating 3 rows instead of just appearing in the first row.

[image: table]

How can I solve that? It is a problem inside my html?

Comment: looks like a problem with the data you're trying to display

Comment: Dear OP, what about this, https://stackoverflow.com/q/71961619/17562044 isn't almost same, you should learn the basics of `dictionary` and `list`, and their methods as well.

Comment: Even if I change the data values to just numbers the problem still remains for me

Comment: @SunderamDubey Its not the same I think, because now my problem is with the format that the values are being represented inside my table.

Comment: Does your `data` dictionary, have three variables, are they `querysets` or only `single_object`, tell only this, also share your full view, from which you are rendering template and sending data into that. See how do I ask a good question [ask].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your HTML table is creating a new row (`<tr>`) for each element, what you want is to create a new cell, (`<td>`) for each each element, like this:

```html
<table class="table">
  <thead>
      <tr>
          <th>Year with most launches</th>
          <th>Launch site with most launches</th>
          <th>Number of launches between 2019 and 2021</th>
      </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>

      <tr>
        {% for element in data.values %}
          <td>{{ element }}</td>
        {% endfor %}
      </tr>

  </tbody>
</table>
```

Of course, this will only produce ONE row, which may be what you want, but if you wanted several rows you would need two loops, an outer one for each `<tr>`, and an inner one for each `<td>`.